# Sort Folders/Copy Folder/File Name by Custom Filter in Windows (Using Extrabits)

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename, batch-rename, file-filter

I am trying to sort and/or copy folders and filenames under Windows 10. I am using a third-party software called Extrabits, which allows me to copy the name of a folder or file. I have two folders, called [A] B and [C] D. Is there anyway I could sort them so that it is arranged like this B [A] and D [C] or at least [B] A or [D] C.

Another way would be to make it or rename it automatically into B by A or D by C.

[image]

Comment: A screen shot would help us understand your question.
StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill I provided a link in the description to the image.

Comment: Why is there a link in your title?

Comment: @Ramhound Apparently no one could see the link in the description.

Comment: @RickJ - It does not belong in the title.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for that.

Comment: Now anyone can help?

Comment: Batch renaming is easy and there is plenty of software (e.g. [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer)), but it's not clear how you want your files/folders to be renamed? Is it a simple swap from "[A] B" to "B [A]" based on the square brackets?

Comment: @dezlov Basically yes. Or another way, [A] B to B by A.

Comment: @dezlov Yes it does thank you. What about if I want it from from "[A] B" to "B [A]" by any chance?

Comment: @RickJ Change the replacement pattern in rule configuration from `$2 by $1` to `$2 [$1]`.

Comment: @dezlov what about switching them regardless of name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping parts of the file name (or folder name) can be achieved with [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer).

Using the following Regular Expressions renaming rule:

```
Replace expression "\A\[(.*?)\](.*)\Z" with "$2 by $1" (skip extension)
```

You can change in the *Filter Settings* whether you want to rename files or folders.

Here is the demo:

[image: ReNamer - swap parts of the file name]